# Getting a DBUpdateConcurrencyExcpetion trying to insert using entity framework model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to insert data into my database using Entity framework model but I keep getting DbUpdateConcurrencyException error as it thinks that there are zero rows to update. 
I imagine I am missing something simple but can someone please point me in the correct direction, thanks.

```
using (var db = new Logtable())
        {
            var log = new Log
            { WebId = 1,
                Time = DateTime.Now

            };

            db.Logs.Add(log);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

From Logtable class

```
public virtual DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
```

Comment: It could be a number of things, Have you checked your SQL Database,  The table will need the Identity seed, setting on the Id field.

Comment: I had the key on the table wrong, my code was correct thanks !